# Learning Days C#

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

How can i learn next wednesday, monday in a week?  Forexample Today 06.02.2009 next Monday 09.02.2009 or wednesday 11.02.2009 there is any algorithm?

i need :

which day monday in comingweek?

findDay("Monday")

it must return 09.02.2009

=====================================================
findDay("Tuesday")

it must return 10.02.2009

Comment: nobugz's answer is what you need. DayOfWeek is an enum. Just copy/paste and use it.

Answer (score 4):

```
public static DateTime GetNextDayDate(DayOfWeek day) {
  DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
  int dayDiff = (int)(now.DayOfWeek - day);
  if (dayDiff <= 0) dayDiff += 7;
  return now.AddDays(dayDiff);
}
```

Comment: You should add sample usage of this function to this excellent answer to make it complete. Just a tip! ;-)

Comment: This would make a great extension method. +1

Comment: I get incorrect results with this. It should be (day - now.DayOfWeek) rather than the other way round.

Answer (score 3):

```
DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
DateTime nextMonday = now.AddDays((int)now.DayOfWeek - (int)DayOfWeek.Monday);
```

Hum it seems that I answered too quickly. Actually there are more checking to do. Have a look at nobugz or peterchen answers.

Comment: Umm... wouldn't that subtract one or more days in most cases?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler solution:

DayOfWeek is an enum, as: Monday=1, Tuesday=2, etc.

So, to get next Monday (from today) you should use:

```
DateTime.Today.AddDays(8-(int)DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek)
```

where "8" is next week's Monday(according to the enum-> 1+7).

Replace the 8 for a 10 (i.e. Wednesday, 3+7) and you'll get next week's Wednesday, and so on...

Answer (score 0):

Like Tyalis, but some extra checking is required:

```
int daysUntilMonday = ((int)DayOfWeek.Monday - (int)today.DayOfWeek;
if (daysUntilMonday <= 0) 
  daysUntilMonday += 7;

Monday = DateTime.Now.AddDays(daysUntilMonday);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just iterate a bit:

```
DateTime baseDate = ...;
DayOfWeek requiredDayOfWeek = ...;

while(baseDate.DayOfWeek != requiredDayOfWeek)
    baseDate = baseDate.AddDays(1);
```

You can also write an extension method if those are available:

```
static Next(this DateTime date, DayOfWeek requiredDayOfWeek) { ... }
```

and you'll get pretty syntax: `today.Next(DayOfWeek.Saturday)`.