# Generate datetime (exp: 09.02.2009) to string date (exp:Monday)

Tags: c#, .net, datetime, date

I am trying to learn or generate any codes to learn string `day("26.02.2009")` ---> give me "wednesday"

I need a static datefunction in C#.

For example:

```
datetime Str_day= Returnstringdate("09.02.2009");  ---->Str_day="Monday";

Returnstringdate("09.02.2009")

{
     it must return Monday!!!
}
```

OR

```
Returnstringdate("09.02.2009 12:30:32")

{
     it must return Monday!!!
}
```

Comment: 26.02.2009 is a Thursday, btw

Comment: You might not get a "ready made" code u 'want'. But if u show more earnestness u might get some help u 'need'.

Answer (score 8):

[`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) allows you to specify the exact format of the date you are parsing. You can then use `ToString("dddd")` to return the day of the week as a string.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("09.02.2009", "dd.MM.yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

string dayOfWeek = date.ToString("dddd");
```

Alternatively you can use the [`DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.dayofweek.aspx) property, which returns a [`System.DayOfWeek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.dayofweek.aspx) enumeration value.

```
DateTime date = DateTime.ParseExact("09.02.2009", "dd.MM.yyyy", 
    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

DayOfWeek day = date.DayOfWeek;
string dayString = day.ToString("G");
```

Though this second option will yield the day of the week as an unlocalized (English) string.

Comment: Note that DateTime.ParseExact requires a third IFormatProvider parameter.

Answer (score 2):

```
    DayOfWeek day = DateTime.ParseExact(
        "26.02.2009", "dd.MM.yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture).DayOfWeek;
    string dayString = day.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `DateTime.DayOfWeek` Property on your DateTime object.

Also see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/520163/learning-days-c).